# Simple Calculator issue in LWC

Tags: lightning-web-components

**The alert shows 0 or NaN value on click of a button (Sum, Subtract, Multiply or Division)**

[image]

Note - Tried removing '0' value from number1 and number2 as well but alert returns 'NaN'.

HTML code

```
<template>
<div class="slds-m-around_small">
    <lightning-card title="Calculator" icon-name="custom:custom34">
        <lightning-input value={number1} 
            label="Number 1" 
            name="number1"
            placeholder="input your number here"
             >
        </lightning-input>
        <lightning-input value={number2} label="Number 2" 
            placeholder="input your number here"
            name="number2"
             >
        </lightning-input> <br/>
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Sum" onclick={doSum} >

        </lightning-button>
        &nbsp;
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Subsc" onclick={doSubsc} >

        </lightning-button>
        &nbsp;
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Div" onclick={doDiv} >

        </lightning-button>
        &nbsp;
        <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Multiplication" onclick={doMulti} >

        </lightning-button>
    </lightning-card>
</div>
```

JS code

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CalculatorCmp extends LightningElement {

    @track number1=0;
    @track number2=0;


    doSum(){
        const sum = parseInt(this.number1) + parseInt(this.number2);
        console.log(this.number1);
        console.log(this.number2);
        alert(sum);
    }
    doSubsc(){
        const subsc = parseInt(this.number1) - parseInt(this.number2);
        console.log("sub" + this.number1);
        console.log("sub" + this.number2);
        alert(subsc);
    }

    doDiv(){
        const divOut = parseInt(this.number1) / parseInt(this.number2);
        alert(divOut);
    }

    doMulti(){
        const multiPli = parseInt(this.number1) * parseInt(this.number2);
        alert(multiPli);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In LWC data will not explicitly bound to the variable as soon as it changes in HTML

You have to explicitly update it by handling evets

```
<template>
<div class="slds-m-around_small">
<lightning-card title="Calculator" icon-name="custom:custom34">
    <lightning-input value={number1} 
        label="Number 1" 
        name="number1"
        onchange={onNumberOneChange}
        placeholder="input your number here"
         >
    </lightning-input>
    <lightning-input value={number2} label="Number 2" 
        placeholder="input your number here"
        name="number2"
        onchange={onNumberTwoChange}
         >
    </lightning-input> <br/>
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Sum" onclick={doSum} >

    </lightning-button>
    &nbsp;
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Subsc" onclick={doSubsc} >

    </lightning-button>
    &nbsp;
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Div" onclick={doDiv} >

    </lightning-button>
    &nbsp;
    <lightning-button variant="brand" label="Multiplication" onclick={doMulti} >

    </lightning-button>
</lightning-card>
```

Update your `number1` and `number2` attribute by handling the event in js file

```
import { LightningElement, track } from 'lwc';

export default class CalculatorCmp extends LightningElement {

@track number1=0;
@track number2=0;

onNumberOneChange (event) {
    this.number1 = event.target.value;
}
onNumberTwoChange (event) {
    this.number2 = event.target.value;
}
doSum(){
    const sum = parseInt(this.number1) + parseInt(this.number2);
    console.log(this.number1);
    console.log(this.number2);
    alert(sum);
}
doSubsc(){
    const subsc = parseInt(this.number1) - parseInt(this.number2);
    console.log("sub" + this.number1);
    console.log("sub" + this.number2);
    alert(subsc);
}

doDiv(){
    const divOut = parseInt(this.number1) / parseInt(this.number2);
    alert(divOut);
}

doMulti(){
    const multiPli = parseInt(this.number1) * parseInt(this.number2);
    alert(multiPli);
}
}
```

Try this and let me know:)

Answer (score 1):

In LWC, data-binding is one-way. You have to read the value from the input fields or handle a change event. You can do this to fix your code:

```
handleInputChange(event) {
  this[event.target.name] = parseFloat(event.target.value);
}
```

---

```
<lightning-input value={number1} onchange={handleInputChange} ...
```

...

```
<lightning-input value={number2} onchange={handleInputChange} ...
```

---

[Playground Example](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/playground/Gmc7txHCQ/1/edit)